# How to set image directory for Primefaces GraphicImage

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a graphicImage component but I couldn't see my loading.gif file. I think there is a problem with file path. My image is under "Web Pages/Resources/images/loading.gif".

I am using Netbeans and 
Here is my page "Web Pages/Pages/customPages/index.xhtml";

```
<p:blockUI block="myDataTable" trigger="myDataTable">  
            Loading<br />  
            <p:graphicImage library="images" value="loading.gif"/>  
        </p:blockUI
```

**EDIT:** These are also didn't work :)

```
library="images" value="loading.gif"
library="resources/images" value="loading.gif"
value="loading.gif"
library="resources" value="loading.gif"
```

**EDIT2:** Here is how I solved this issue but I don't think it is a good solution. Is there any other way?

```
value="#{FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()}/resources/images/loading.gif"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you use `library` attributte you shouldn't use `value` attributte. Use `name` attributte instead. Try:

```
<p:graphicImage library="images" name="loading.gif" />
```

Comment: <p:graphicImage library="images" name="loading.gif" /> worked for me thanks for your help. You can edit your answer.

Comment: Using the library like this is bad practice ,see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used/11988418

Answer (score 1):

use the attributte library to indicate the folder that is inside the resources folder

```
<p:graphicImage library="images" name="loading.gif" />
```

if you use subfolders

```
<p:graphicImage library="images" name="folder1/folder2/loading.gif" />
```

Comment: How is this fundamentally different from the  13 upvoted and accepted answer (the 'subfolders' is not a fundamental difference).  and using the library  like this is bad practice, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used/11988418